# Cardinal arithmetic argument for countability of finite subsets of integers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am trying to prove that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable. I proved that the set of all infinite sequences of $\mathbb{Z}$ is uncountable, simply by using a bit of cardinal arithmetic.

I'm familiar with the usual proof for my problem - indicating a bijection between finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$, and then using some inductive argument to show that the finite subsets of the naturals are countable.... that's all good. But I was curious as to whether there is a more direct approach with cardinal arithmetic.

I was playing around with taking the union of all of the possible finite subsets of the integers and attempting to find the cardinality of that set (and felt like I was on to something), but have had a hard time actually formulating the result. Does this seem like a reasonable approach, and if not are there any other proof mechanisms for this problem?

Comment: Do you know: The atmost countable union of atmost countable sets is atmost countable? Can you apply it here?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг That's fair, it could be applied directly for an easy proof. If possible I'd rather just apply something strictly for my case however.

Comment: By that, you mean you can implement what I said, right? And that gives a proof, right?

Comment: Recommend you study the basics of the theory of ordinals.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}.$  Here's an explicit bijection $i$ mapping $S$ to $\mathbb{N}\!:$

$$i(A)=\sum_{\substack{n\in A\\n\ge 0}}4^{n}+\frac12\sum_{\substack{n\in A\\n\lt 0}}4^{-n}.$$

An empty sum here is equal to $0,$ as usual.

I'm taking $\mathbb{N}$ to mean $\lbrace 0, 1, 2, \dots\rbrace.$  If you don't want to count $0$ as a member of $\mathbb{N},$ add $1$ to the formula.

It's a good exercise to see why this works.  (Hint: it uses binary representation of natural numbers.)

Comment: This is what I mentioned I already knew how to do in my question, but thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it seemed different to me from the proof I imagined you were referring to (since this avoids an explicit inductive proof, assuming that you already know the basic properties of binary representation).

Comment: It is a bit different and I do appreciate it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Z and N have the same cardinality.So we need to prove that the set of all finite subsets of N is countable.Given any natural number n consider the set {1,2,....,n}.This set has 2^n number of subsets.Let An be the set of all subsets of {1,2,...,n}.Therefore An is finite for each n belonging to the set of natural numbers.Now take the union of all An's. Now the union is countable union of finite sets so it will be countable.Now if B is any finite subset of N then B belongs to the union.Hence the proof.

Comment: Could be a good answer with a little work on the formatting.